# Buying a new VSTS hosted pipeline in middle of the month not starting

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have picked up project the is hosted in vsts.
When doing checking in I was given the error message.

Your account has no Build or Release minutes remaining.

After reading the documentation I have found, that I am using a hosted pipeline, and have gone through my 240 minutes.
I purchased another pipeline for this using my azure pay as you go account, that is linked to vsts.

It does not seem to show at https://{vstsName}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_buildQueue?_a=resourceLimits. I try and buy another it shows I already have one. Do I have to wait till the start of the month to activate my unlimited hosted pipelines?

Is there anyway to get round this?
Is it possible to just check in by pass this step?

Comment: How do you checkin the code for now, are you use gated checkin, checkin policy etc? And can you confirm if you bought Hosted pipeline succeed? Once the Hosted pipeline bought, you should use it even it in the middle of a month.

Comment: Are you sure you purchased a hosted pipeline and not a private pipeline